# sbt - include additional source directories

Tags: scala, sbt

I have two projects, where Main depends on Dependency.

By default, Dependency compiles just fine, but Main fails because it doesn't know about Dependency's source.

One solution that I came up with was to simply add a symbolic link in Main's src directory pointing to Dependency's source, but I feel like there must be a better way in SBT.

Is there a simple way to tell SBT about other source directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Easiest and idiomatic:
Declare dependency in `Build.scala`

```
lazy val main = Project(id = "Main",
                         base = file("Main")) dependsOn(dependent)
lazy val dependent = Project(id = "Dependent",
                         base = file("Dependent"))
```

2) Not so cool, but you can [specify](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/v0.10.1/main/Defaults.scala#L111) where sbt will look at for sources.